# What exactly does GitHub's "create a new project" menu item "Git ignore" do?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I though gitignore was just a file where you could specify which files you didn't want checked into your repo. Then, I saw in the menu to create a new repo, the option to specify a git ignore like so:

[image]

I thought git ignore was for files. What does it even mean to git ignore Windows? or C++? And why can you only choose one?

Comment: GitHub help is a nightmare, that's why I don't vote to close this question, even while the details of the current gui of an online site would probably be obsolete very soon.

Comment: *"And why can you only choose one?"* : It just looks like a poor design.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Because they are tailored specifically for the type.  Isuka mentioned Visual Studio, but the files ignored in the VS project types are also in the C# and VB.NET ignored files.

Comment: @Powerlord All my big projects would need more than one of those sets. But I guess this is more an option for beginners.

Comment: @DenysSéguret There's nothing to stop you from editing the `.gitignore` after it's created.

Comment: Designing GUIs is hard! In this context I'd think that it would be pretty obvious that an entry labeled X means "ignore stuff related/specific to X", but apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you select something there, GitHub is adding a `.gitignore` file to your new repo with a set of ignore patterns that typically are useful for the kind of thing you selected. If you e. g. select `Java`, the file will contain

```
# Ignore patterns for Java
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*
```

Answer (score 1):

`.gitignore` is for telling Git which files to ignore for tracking purposes. This function within GitHub is just a quick-start/helper which will provide a basic, pre-populated, `.gitignore` file based on the type of repo you specify it is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct there. `.gitignore` is there to remove files that are not wanted in the repository. But be careful, the options there don't mean "remove Windows" or "remove C++". By selecting one of those options, GitHub will provide for your project one specific `.gitignore` file that will suit best what you are working on. For instance, selecting the Visual Studio option will provide you [this .gitignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) which removes files such as .suo or .vs files. If you select [the C++ one](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/C%2B%2B.gitignore), it will be a different one best suited for C++ projects.

You can find a list of all the `.gitignore` template files used by GitHub [there](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Answer (score 0):

You were right. The `.gitignore` file specifies what you want to exclude from tracking inside your repository. That function basically creates a start `.gitignore` file with Windows files you most often don't need tracked inside your repo. Installation files, archives, image thumbnail, iconfiles created by your image viewer or similar...

For example:

```
# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Windows Installer files
*.cab
*.msi
*.msm
*.msp

# Windows shortcuts
*.lnk
```